# Active Admin: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, activeadmin

I am using activeadmin version: 1.0.0.pre 168d72e
It is working fine in development But got following error on heroku.

> app[web.1]:
> **ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):**
>
> app[web.1]:     **1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)**
>
> app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/will_paginate-3.0.7/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:149:in `select_for_count' 2

[Same issue listed here:](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/3278)

Please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: try closing `renderer_for(:index)` into parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, But how can I change the line in gem code:
https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, its because ActiveAdmin uses Kaminari instead of will_paginate.
In the end, I switched to Kaminari, because it seemed to be better, and its still improving.

However, there is note about compatibility here: [ActiveAdmin installation notes](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/0-installation.html)

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer, I added will_paginate compatibility from given link and it worked fine. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another code to handle this problem:

```
# config/initializers/kaminari.rb
if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate 
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationMethods
        def per(value = nil) per_page(value) end
        def total_count() count end
      end
    end
    module CollectionMethods
      alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
    end
  end
end
```

**Active Admin** provides its own solution for [`will_paginate`](https://activeadmin.info/0-installation.html) (at the very bottom of the page) but it does not work for me.

- Rails version: `5.1.6`
- `will_paginate` version: `3.1.6`
- `activeadmin` version: `1.4.3`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that problem was related to to included `gem factory_girl_rails` inside `development` group. Removing this, fixed the issue.